# Remove product after an order has been placed in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I'm using the most recent versions of WordPress and WooCommerce.

I'm aware this might seem weird out of context, but I wanna add a hook to my functions.php that removes a certain product by ID from an order after the order has been placed.

Here is what I am working with so far:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->get_id()==10766) {
          $order->remove_item( $item->get_id() );
        }
    }
    return $order_id;
}
```

I am trying to remove the product with the ID 10766 from the order if said product is part of the order.
I took this from a different, older post here so the code itself might not be perfect. It definitely isn't working.

**Update after some experimentation:**
With the help of Cameron Hurd, I tried the following code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);

function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->get_id() === 10766) {
            $order->remove_item( $item->get_id() );
        }
    }

    $order->save_items();

    return $order_id;
}
```

This seemed promising, but pressing the checkout button will submit an empty order while also throwing an empty WooCommerce error message leaving the user on the checkout page.

After this I had 2 ideas:
1.) Changing `remove_item` to `wc_delete_order_item`. I really don't know the difference and changing it didn't seem to make a difference either.
2.) Changing the hook so it happens after the order is in the back end. I tried changing it from `woocommerce_new_order` to `woocommerce_thankyou`. This however broke the thank you page in addition to doing nothing to the order.

This is what I'm sitting with now:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);

function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $current_item_id = $item->get_id();
        if ( $current_item_id === 10766) {
            $order->remove_item($current_item_id);
        }
    }

    $order->save_items();

    return $order_id;
}
```

Still looking for a working answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` action hook,
where you then specify the product id.

So you get:

```php
function custom_process_order( $order_id ) {
    if( ! $order_id ) return;

    // get order object
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    
    // get order items = each product in the order
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
        
        if ( $product->get_id() == 10766 ) {
            $order->remove_item( $item->get_id() );
        }
    }
    
    // Calculate
    $order->calculate_totals();
    
    // Save
    $order->save();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsing the code from `abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php`, where the `remove_item` method is located... I see that items are added to an array called `items_to_delete`. That variable shows up again in `save_items`, where each item class to be deleted has its [`delete`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Data.html#180-194) method invoked.

```
<?php
// abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php

abstract class WC_Abstract_Order extends WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order {

    /**
     * Remove item from the order.
     *
     * @param int $item_id Item ID to delete.
     * @return false|void
     */
    public function remove_item( $item_id ) {
        $item      = $this->get_item( $item_id, false );
        $items_key = $item ? $this->get_items_key( $item ) : false;

        if ( ! $items_key ) {
            return false;
        }

        // Unset and remove later.
        $this->items_to_delete[] = $item;
        unset( $this->items[ $items_key ][ $item->get_id() ] );
    }

    // ...

    /**
     * Save all order items which are part of this order.
     */
    protected function save_items() {
        $items_changed = false;

        foreach ( $this->items_to_delete as $item ) {
            $item->delete();
            $items_changed = true;
        }
        $this->items_to_delete = array();

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Therefore, you might try calling `$order->save_items()` after the foreach loop in your custom action:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);

function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->get_id() === 10766) {
            $order->remove_item( $item->get_id() );
        }
    }

    $order->save_items();

    return $order_id;
}
```

Comment: This worked well, thank you for the in-depth answer! One issue I still have that if said product is the only product in the cart, the user can't check out (which makes sense). Woocommerce shows an empty error message. Is there a way to either remove the product after the full order has been placed or fill in the error message?

Comment: I've re-tested this and even when adding more products, I get an empty woocommerce error message and the order is placed but is completely empty. I tried hooking into both `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` and `woocommerce_thankyou` instead but neither does the trick. maybe there's still an issue in the code?